# Visual Studio MAC .Net Core: How to debug using iPhone?

Tags: c#, iphone, visual-studio, asp.net-core, ssl

I encounter this problem. I need to debug my API using my iPhone. I run the project using a custom configuration:

```
App Url: https://192.168.0.145:6001
```

This IP address will be the access point. The problem is that whenever I tried to access from my iPhone, this error shows:

```
[Error] Could not connect to the server. 
[Error] The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.0.145” which could put your confidential information at risk.
[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://192.168.0.145:6001/owner/ownerLogin due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “192.168.0.145” which could put your confidential information at risk. (ownerLogin, line 0)
```

It seems that I have to trust my SSL certificate. I then download the SSL certificate and install it, but then I cannot see any certificate to allow in my `Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings`.

How do I solve this problem? How can I debug my API ran from Visual Studio Mac using my iPhone?

Comment: Did you turn on trust? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477?force_isolation=true#:~:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20turn,Mobile%20Device%20Management%20(MDM).  It may already be trusted.  Did you try to run your code after installing the certificate?

Comment: The certificate does not show in the phone setting. The certificate is issued by the localhost, but I have to access it from LAN IP, this causes the error. Right now I have a solution which I dont like, which is to use ngrok. It is slow.

Comment: You need to get the certificate from the local host.  If you do not like getting by IP, can you get the file anther way?  Maybe FTP? You only need to get the certificate once.  The expiration date of certificate is usually a few years.

Comment: The certificate is issued by localhost, which is invalid if used by IP address.

Comment: You could be having one or both of these issues 1) No route between client and server.  You can test by using PING 2) The certificate is not loaded on both client and server.  I do not think this is the issue since you can get it to work with ngrok.  ngrok looks like it is creating a tunnel to create a connection between two networks.  You may have a firewall that is blocking a direct connection between the two networks and the real solution is to unblock a port number in the firewall.  I would start by using PING to see if there is a route.  If there is a route, than a port is being blocked.

Comment: There is no problem with the connection, the connection between the device and the server exist. The certificate is loaded on the server and client, but it is not valid under IP address. It is only valid under `localhost`. The problem is that the certificate cannot be installed on the device, it cannot be found in the settings, e even after downloading the certificate in the device.

Comment: The errors says "Could not connect to the server" which mean the connection does NOT exist.